# PHP connection to remote MySQL database acces denied, but it does work in Java

Tags: java, php, mysql, connection

When I try to connect to a remote database using PHP I get an error saying: 'Access denied for user: ...'
I am new to PHP and I don't know if my code is correct, here is the code I am using.

```
<?php
$host = 'adress:port';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'name'

$con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($con->connect_errno){
    die('Error ' . $this->con->connect_error);
}
echo 'Connected successfully!';
?>
```

All the variables are correct.
When I try the following code in Java I do have acces to said database.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

class MySQLConnect {
    private final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://adress:port/name";
    private final String USERNAME = "username";
    private final String PASSWORD = "password";

    private Connection connection;
    private Properties properties;

    public MySQLConnect() {
    }

    private Properties getProperties() {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", USERNAME);
            properties.setProperty("password", PASSWORD);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    public Connection connect() {
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, getProperties());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection mySQLConnect = new MySQLConnect().connect();
        System.out.println(mySQLConnect);
    }
}
```

I know I have access to the database and I have permissions to login, but I can't seem to figure out how to connect with it in PHP. I have written the password and username correct, and I have tried alot of combinations for the $host variable but all of them do not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The error message says, that the user (in the database) is not allowed to login, eg. a rights issue with the user, not a network related problem. If that was the case, you'd get something like "connection refused" or so

Comment: Is the php client running on exactly the same box as the Java client and are you using exactly the same credentials?

Comment: I use the exact same credentials, I don't understand what you mean by 'box' but both clients are running on the exact same pc if that is what you are asking.

Comment: "box" is a slang word for a PC, so yes that's what g00se is saying.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the full error message, not an abbreviated version.